# Trying to open a Chromium Browser via a shell_exec command from a user accessing the device?

Tags: php, raspberry-pi3

My device does not have a touchscreen, so the user accesses features via their phone over WiFi and the device sits as a local webserver. I'm trying to get it so if a user submits to a form it will run a command to open up a Chromium browser on the device.

Right now It shows output on the user's phone, but nothing happens on the device. I understand the security concerns, but only the single user has access to the device this way and must be in close proximity.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){  

    //if user clicked "video on"
    if(isset($_POST["video_on"])){
    echo shell_exec('./video_on.sh');   
    }
}
```

Now here is video_on.sh:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    DISPLAY=:0 chromium-browser --incognito --start-maximized --kiosk 
    http://localhost/videoloop
```

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot start anything on the remote users device by running PHP code on the server. That could only start a browser on your raspberry

Answer (score 0):

`www-data` does not have access to your xserver (display) running, so chromium will start without screen output, in background. You have to run your webserver as a user that is currently logged into the startx server, easiest way to do this is to call a php embedded server in terminal from the X server to ensure that you have all necesarry permissions.

Comment: See my comment above

Answer (score 0):

On terminal `which chromium-browser`
add the path chromium-browser to visudo.

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/chromium-browser
```

on php

```
shell_exec('DISPLAY=:0 sudo -u yourusername chromium-browser https://www.google.com/');
}
```